# Linux CentOS Server Startscript: Minecraft Server

Tags: linux, centos, sh, minecraft

Recently tried using the following startscript here:

http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/linux-server-startscript-menu/

After installing dos2unix, it says it is installed and using the latest version. I then use the command "dos2unix startserver.sh" and I prompted with the message: "dos2unix: converting file startserver.sh to UNIX format ..." and then it returns to the next blank command line. Problem is there is nothing actually starting the script or I am missing something. I have tried talking to the owner of this script and he helped me to this point, but is unsure what to do next. He says he uses debian and is less familiar with CentOS and so I am posting here.

Here is my script that has been edited according to my server. The most important change I made is SCRIPTUPDATE="0" (so it doesn't update)

Please keep in mind that I am very new to linux and any operating systems in general.

Answer (score 0):

The dos2unix command converts the newline characters in a file from dos format to unix format. This is just for cleaning up a file that may have problems (e.g., from a bad ftp transfer).

Try running the ./startserver.sh command again, now that the file has been cleansed.

Comment: After its converted to UNIX format, I enter the command ./startserver.sh and it acts as if nothing happened. It just returns to the next command line. Image: http://imgur.com/jXoVdH1